Is there a way for a function to return non nullable value even if it has possibility to return one?
I am calling a simple function that returns a duration object. However, it is null at times. I want to modify the code so that it can return only a duration object and not duration? object.
  factory ExecutionModel.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data()!;
    return ExecutionModel(
        selfRef: snapshot.reference,
        state: TimerState.fromString(data['state']),
        timeAdded: fromJsonDuration(data['duration'] as int), // this line
        activeTimerRef: data['activeTimerRef'],
        paused: fromJsonDateTime(data['paused'] as Timestamp),
        started: fromJsonDateTime(data['started'] as Timestamp));

Duration fromJsonDuration(int milliseconds) {
  return Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds);
}

Here timeAdded argument is a Duration object and not Duration? object. But it can occasionally have null values. What is the fix around for this? I don't want to change timeAdded to Duration? as it can affect other areas.

if you are returning return Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds); then no, it cannot be null - why do you think that fromJsonDuration's return value is null?

When I am running the unit test it is giving me an error 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast' and is pointing to this line in the code.

this is because data['duration'] is null so it cannot cast data['duration'] as int - this is explained by the error message you are getting: 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast' 

okay. I changed the timeAdded from required to zero as default.
const ExecutionModel({
required this.selfRef,
required this.state,
this.activeTimerRef,
this.started,
this.paused,
this.timeAdded = const Duration(microseconds: 0),
});                                                                                                                                   I am still getting the same error. The firebase now has 0 value (int).

Its working now. I changed to  timeAdded: fromJsonDuration(data['duration'] ?? 0. But now has problem for paused. type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp' in type cast.

this is the same case as 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast'

As already explained in the comments, the underlying problem here is that the received JSON might contain a null value for duration or is missing a duration entry at all.
Any access to a Map returns a nullable value because if the given key does not exist in the Map it won't throw an exception but return null. (which was probably the reason you added the cast)
So you have two possibilities to deal with this behavior of Maps:
If you know that it will always contain the key you need, add a ! like:
timeAdded: fromJsonDuration(data['duration']!)`

then you would get a proper exception in case the key is missing.
If you know that the json you receive might miss the "duration" key, you have to check for null first like:
timeAdded: data['duration'] != null ? fromJsonDuration(data['duration']) 
                  : const Duration({your default duration});

(replace {your default duration} with the value you want to use as default)
Looking at what your fromJsonDuration does, the even better solution to achieve the same would be:
timeAdded: Duration(milliseconds: data['duration'] ?? 0)


because it doesn't do two lookups into the map while clearly expressing what it is doing.
As a side note, you shouldn't need any of the type-casts that you use because either the map contains the value in the types your functions expect or a type-cast would not help.

@MisterMiyagi why not just using ?? 0 ? Because it is far better to define a duration in terms of milliseconds or seconds than as an int.  0 doesn't  say anything about what it means at that point. But I agree there is an even better way

@MisterMiyagi the underlying cause isn't an int? because a Map<String,dynamic> returns just null and has no idea of a type.

See my latest edit. doing a ?? 0 inside the function call as used in the original code doesn't express what is passed to the function.

what if the default should be something else than 0? And the naming of the conversion function is pretty bad, and adding abstraction without any value isn't something we should encourage
Maybe WWE can delete some of the comments after we are finshed

you could rename the function to durationFromMilliseconds() but that is what the constructor of Duration does

Try this
Duration fromJsonDuration(int? milliseconds) {
  if (milliseconds != null) {
    return Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds);
  } else {
    return Duration.zero; // or any other default value.
  }
}


this one doesn't help because the root problem isn't being null but it tries to cast a null value to an int. you have to test for null before making that cast

Please consider to [edit] this answer to 1) provide an explanation how and why this works and 2) show the auxiliary code changes required. As-is this code can't be just plugged into the question code.

"Is there a way for a function to return non nullable value even if it has possibility to return one?" The question itself returning a non nullable value so i returned zero incase of null
